# Change file location in iTunes

Tags: itunes

I changed my iTunes Media Library location. The previous location was a network drive and the songs were downloaded to that drive. I've changed the location to a local drive and want to download to the local drive. However the individual songs still reference the location in the network drive and therefore prevents me from downloading a local copy. How can I change the file location references for my library?

Comment: In Itunes->Preferences->Advanced what are the choices set to?

Comment: Generally you copy the whole iTunes folder to the new location and then set that as the new location in iTunes Preferences. Once that is set and confirmed working you can delete the original.